# Jenkins Pipeline - Can we restart jenkins pipeline again with the same build number?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline and when I try replay or restart from stage option in case of any build failure, it is creating a new build.

Example: One of the job in pipeline is to do scp of build to remote location. So when this got failed I tried replay and restart from stage option, but it again started generating new build.

So what can I do to generate build again with the same failed build number instead of new one?

Comment: It is theoretically possible but would require a lot of effort and is generally not best practice. Is there a reason why you need the same build number?

Comment: Here in my case build artifacts are generated successfully but scp to remote location is failed. So I copied my build artifacts manually and finished testing. Now I want to promote this build so other stakeholders can use this as official build, but to do promotion it is not visible under promotion tab. Only successful builds are visible under promotion tab. So is there any way to trigger build again with same number or can we mimic somehow to make this failed build visible under promotion tab ?

Comment: If scp fails rarely it shouldn't be so bad to just restart the build with a new build number. Otherwise you could consider doing some form of error handling with that. You could even move the failing part to another job which is triggered by the first one.

Comment: We just want to avoid testing again with new build because it requires lot of time and effort. As this current tested build is well and good and tested we want to promote only this build. Please help me on this to trigger the build with same number or any other possibility to make this build visible under promotion tab.

Comment: In that case you could edit the `nextBuildNumber` file in the job (somewhere on the server) and do a replay where you delete all pipeline code you dont want to run again and change the rest to work for the different circumstances. Maybe the copyArtifact plugin could be helpful as well. From here on out the devil is in the details (which you have to work out yourself I guess). Good luck